# Wrap HTML around existing elements

Tags: javascript, css

This is my normal css to apply :

```
<h3><strong><span style="color: #3399ff;"></span></strong></h3>
```

I wish to apply that style above to these js elements:

```
$('#no_tax_price').text("$"+no_tax_price.toFixed(2));
        $('#tax').text("$"+tax.toFixed(2));
        $('#tax_price').text("$"+(no_tax_price+tax).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: You mean jQuery elements? http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: you simply want to apply a color to those elements? I'd simply create a class that sets the color and apply the class to the elements using jQuery. If that's not what you meant, please clarify.

Comment: Yeah so essentially, using jquery the $ price updates , to say $34.00 and I wish to bind that output inbetween the tags I showed above. <h3><strong><span style="color: #3399ff;">$34.00</span></strong></h3>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define your styles in CSS rather than HTML, your new elements will automatically take on the styling - no JS required.

```
#no_tax_price, #tax, #tax_price {
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #3399ff;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally I wouldn't use `<h3><strong><span>` to apply styles (instead just use a single class with the right CSS properties defined), but a quick fix is to just wrap those elements around the contents of your "jQuery elements":

```
$('#no_tax_price, #tax, #tax_price')
    .wrapInner('<h3><strong><span style="color: #3399ff;"></span></strong></h3>');
```

Comment: actually, I want to add a different class to each element

Comment: @422 What's your "class" because I only see elements in your question. Can you edit it to show what you mean?

Comment: I strongly concur with Box9's first comment: there is no good reason I can think of to put a `<strong>` element inside your `<h3>`, and absolutely no reason to wrap a span with a style on it.